# When should we switch from an internal FPGA oscillator to an external one?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, oscillator, clock, crystal

I'm about to design a 5Mbps UART on a ICE40U0-5k and I've got a hunch I'll need an external oscillator when I spin my own board after I'm done with the dev board, but I would like to know how I can figure out in general when I need to use an external oscillator or crystal instead of the internal oscillator.

At what point does it become necessary (max frequency inside vs max jitter allowed?) and what metrics should be analysed with what kind of tools to decide.
My first guess is that I should use the timing analyser of the IDE and that somehow  a) it knows the performance of the internal oscillator b) there is a way to enter the performance of external oscillators in the tool - but this is all very vague and uncertain.

In this specific instance it is said the oscillator's frequency varies from chip to chip by +/-10% but I don't see any issue in calibrating this for a given board that's not going to be mass-produced.

I've done my usual sweep online and could not answer this question... I'm hoping to contribute to others' own searches with this post as well.

Comment: I didn't even know FPGAs had internal oscillators lol. It's so much work and cost to implement an FPGA though...is not adding an external oscillator really worth it?

Comment: And I thought they were more common that your answer suggests :) The ICE40UP has one as well as non volatile OTP configuration memory. Nice touch.

Comment: I think your guesses are right, although I don't know Lattice tools, only Xilinx Vivado. Presumably you would use an external one if the internal one doesn't fit your needs for some reason, and frequency and jitter would certainly be two reasons why it might not.

Comment: Is it an internal RC oscillator? Those are relatively crude and not at all accurate

Comment: @user253751 feel free to answer anyway, I'm sure the concepts are identical between both brands

Comment: yeah but the specific timing tools are totally different and I'm not sure the Xilinx part I used even had an internal oscillator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer assumes we are talking about internal RC oscillators)

In general, being able to use an internal RC oscillator vs a dedicated crystal or oscillator is not a question of production quantity, but rather based on the specific application.

Internal RC oscillators are absolutely horrid and, at least in MCUs, are only used to execute a few instructions immediately after boot before transitioning to a higher quality external clock. For a 5Mbps UART or any other asynchronous protocol, there are two major issues for using an RC oscillator.

1. Absolute frequency error: This is the +/-10% number you cited above. Yes, technically you can calibrate this out. I don't see how you could do this other than with trial and error or with lab equipment. More of an annoyance than anything.
2. Frequency stability: I doubt internal RC oscillators come with any guarantees about stability over time or temperature. Sure, it may work in the lab for a bit, but I would be very surprised if it worked consistently and over the entirety of the development cycle.

So to answer your question, I think you can still feel comfortable with an RC oscillator for lower speed synchronous interfaces. Other than that, I feel like the few cents or dollars you save in parts is not worth the headache of debugging intermittent failures due to a marginal timing source.

Comment: In summary...  Use an external oscillator whenever the internal oscillator is not accurate and stable enough for your application.  And assume that in most cases the internal oscillator won't be accurate enough.

Comment: Some applications don't need any real timing accuracy at all, in which case you could just as well use an RC oscillator. I made a box that randomly beeps at you, and I do not care at all whether the beeps at +/- 10% in frequency or interval or even if the synchronous serial control protocol runs 10% fast or slow.